# OpenCV version 4.1.0 drawContours error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'drawContours'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I have the following code that worked well with OpenCV 3.4.1 and now is not working with OpenCV 4.1.0 and gives an error. I do not know how to adapt the code with the newer version, can you help me with that? Thanks a lot

```
def ImageProcessing(image):
    image = cv2.absdiff(image, background)
    h, gray = cv2.threshold(image, 65, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)

    kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)

    gray = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations=1)#1

    des = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
    tmp = cv2.findContours(des,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contour, hier = tmp[1], tmp[0]

    for cnt in contour:
        cv2.drawContours(des,[cnt],0,255,-1)

    gray = cv2.bitwise_not(des)

    gray = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=1)#1

    return gray
```

The error is

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp:2509: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'drawContours'

Comment: Try printing out [cnt]. Is it a list of points?

Comment: `contour, hier = tmp[1], tmp[0]` -- That's wrong. First element of the result tuple is the contour, second is hierarchy. Read the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the OpenCV version, `cv2.findContours()` has varying return signatures.

In OpenCV 3.4.X, [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) returns 3 items

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])
```

In OpenCV 4.1.X, [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) returns 2 items

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])
```

You can easily obtain the contours regardless of the version like this:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
```

Since the last two values are always the same, we can further condense it into a single line using `[-2:]` to extract the contours from the tuple returned by `cv2.findContours()`

```
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
```

Comment: "condense it into a single line using [-2:]",  is actually a brilliant hack

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will work irrespective of the OpenCV version installed in your system/environment and will also store all the tuples in individual variables.

First, get the version of OpenCV installed (we don't want the entire version just the major number ***either 3 or 4***) :

```
import cv2
version = cv2.__version__[0]
```

Based on the version either of the following two statements will be executed and the corresponding variables will be populated:

```
if version == str(4):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

elif version == str(3):
    im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

The contours returned from the function in either scenarios will be stored in `contours`.

> ***Note:*** the above snippet is written assuming either version 3 or 4 of OpenCV is installed. For older versions, please refer to the documentation or update to the latest.