# Camera Capture + Stepper Motor

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am having a problem since im new at the opencv python language, any idea when the camera capture the stepper motor will rotate in 90 degrees.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [too many values to unpack calling cv2.findContours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960257/too-many-values-to-unpack-calling-cv2-findcontours)

Comment: Take a look at [OpenCV 4.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854810/opencv-version-4-1-0-drawcontours)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using opencv 4. In opencv 3 in `cv2.findContours` writting `_, contours, hierarchy` was correct because three arguments were returned. However, in opencv 4 only two arguments are returned so change your statement to `contours, hierarchy`