# Problem with OpenCV cv2.findCountours function not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, opencv

yesterday I successfully updated from openCv version 3.4 to 4.1.2 (on a raspberry pi). I tried out an older program, but it seems like I got an error. I already know that some functions may changed due to to update, but how can I fix this problem:

Code (a piece of):

```
img_blk, contours_blk, hierarchy_blk = cv2.findContours(line.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

[Output on the raspi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzqFL.jpg)

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV version 4.1.0 drawContours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854810/opencv-version-4-1-0-drawcontours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question: 
[OpenCV version 4.1.0 drawContours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854810/opencv-version-4-1-0-drawcontours)

Change your code as follows:

```
contours_blk, hierarchy_blk = cv2.findContours(line.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```