# cv2.contourArea will always return an error

Tags: python, opencv, contour

No matter what I try I can't seem to get cv2.contourArea to work properly, it will always return the error:

> (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea'

My code is trying to find the largest contour in an image and remove the rest with this code:

```
def find_biggest_contour(image):

# Copy to prevent modification
image = image.copy()

_,contours  = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#get contour sizes and return the biggest contour
max_area = -1
for i in range(len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    if area>max_area:
        biggest_contour = contours[i]
        max_area = area

#create an empty mask
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)

#draw the biggest contour on it
cv2.drawContours(mask, [biggest_contour], -1, 255, -1)

return mask
```

Comment: Do you actually have any contours? You need a binary image to get contours and the regions must be white. I do not see any thresholding. What is your `len(contours)`

Comment: See answer below from @vscv.  I think your order of contours and hierarchy are swapped. But the order and number of return values is version dependent. What version of OpenCV are you using.  For example in 4.1.1 it is described at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0. Thus you are feeding contourArea the hierarchy not the contour for that index.

Comment: welcome. please review [ask]. you are expected to debug your code. here you should have looked at the value of that variable (both actually, that are returned by findContours) and considered whether that makes sense.

Comment: The number of return values from `cv2.findContours()` has changed over time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854810/opencv-version-4-1-0-drawcontours-error-215assertion-failed-npoints-0-in/55857838#55857838

Comment: Thank you all! The hierarchy was reversed as I was using an older example for my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's just the return value order is reversed.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours()
```

ps. This work for cv 4.x, 5.x.

***4.x*** https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0

***5.x*** https://docs.opencv.org/5.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0

Comment: Probably, but the number and order are version dependent.

Comment: still, that seems to be the issue, because the snake *did not* complain about `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: This was the problem, it turns out that most documentation on this function is out of date and will tell you that it's the other way around.